# How can I query with `sql function` in dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to send query with `MySQL function expression` in dplyr.

If I want to truncate timestamp at date in MySQL

```
# MySQL
select date(created_at_timestamp) from table
```

would work.

But Following `dplyr` code doesn't work.

```
# dplyr
a <- tbl(conn, 'table_a')
a %>% select(x = DATE(created_at)) %>% show_query()
```

Comment: What is the type of the `created_at` column?  If already a date, then maybe you can eliminate the call to `DATE()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wraping with `sql()` and `mutate` worked.

```
a %>% mutate(x = sql("DATE(created_at)")) %>% show_query()
```